# NestJS Swagger define array in input request

Tags: swagger, nestjs

How I can define following required params in Swagger using NestJS, for example following ID are order to manipulate orders controller.

```
    [
        [
            "1"
        ],
        [
            "2"
        ],
        [
            "3"
        ],
        [
            "4"
        ],
        [
            "5"
        ],
        [
            "6"
        ],
        [
            "7"
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: Does each nested array contain just 1 value or may contain several values? Can you also post the code/annotations that you've tried so far and indicate how it didn't work?

Comment: Reading sheet and got those values, so just wanted to define example in Swagger.